# SQL Server reading Sharepoint List

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have a SQL Server, and I have one specific data source I need to ingest that is coming from a SharePoint list.  What's the best way to go about ingesting that data?  It needs to be repeatable so I can do this on a regular basis....

Comment: How much do you know about the SharePoint environment hosting the list? For example, is it online or on-premises? And what version is it (2007, 2010, 2013, 2016)?

Comment: Have you looked into SSIS? There are built in components for pulling data from a sharepoint list.

Comment: SSIS is what I'll be using.  I didn't realize that the SharePoint list source is built in.  Thanks for pointing it out, and I'll take a look.